# JavaScript - Toggle "check all" checkboxes true/false

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make "toggle checkboxes" function, as below:

HTML Code:

```
<!-- "Check all" box -->
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_00" onclick="selectbox( this.getAttribute( 'id' ));" />
<!-- the other ones -->
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_03" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function selectbox( eID ) {

    // instead of writing the element id in the html code,
    // i want to use "this.getAttribute( 'id' )"
    var c   = document.getElementById( eID );

    // now when we've got the id of the element,
    // let's get the required attribute.
    var box = c.getAttribute( 'name' );

    // set var i value to 0, in order to run "for i" loop
    var i   = 0;

    for(i; i < box.length; i++) {

        // now lets find if the main box (as box[0]) checked.
        // if returns true (it has been checked), then check all - else -
        // do not check 'em all.
        if(box[0].checked == true) {

            box[i].checked  = true;

        }
        else {

            box[i].checked  = false;

        }

    }

}
```

I don't want any jQuery solution (even if it can be easier than pure js), so please avoid suggesting it. All I want to know is - If I'm wrong - what do you think I should do to solve this?
Thank you very much. every suggestion/tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem mainly seems to be that you are iterating over the checkbox name, not the checkboxes *with* that name.

```
var box = c.getAttribute( 'name' );
```

Now, `box` is equal to `"check"`, so `box[0]` is `"c"`, `box[1]` is `"h"` etc.

You need to add this:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByName(box);
```

And then iterate over `boxes`.

Of course, at that point, you may want to rename your variables too.

Answer (score 0):

Given the name in the variable `box`, you can check all boxes with the same name like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName(box), function(el) {
    el.checked = true;
});
```

(`Array.prototype.forEach.call` is used to loop over the "fake-array" returned by `getElementsByName` because the `NodeList` class doesn't have `forEach`.)

I think you can further simply your code by not passing the element's ID to your function, but directly the name (`selectbox(this.name)`). Also note that you can access ID and name using `.id` and `.name` instead of using `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple.

HTML Code:

```
input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_00" onclick="selectbox(this.getAttribute('name'));" />      
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="cbx_00_03" />
```

Javascript:

```
function selectbox(eID) {       
        var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName(eID);

        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes .length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[0].checked) {
                checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                checkBoxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If we're trying to make it simpler, you can do away with the `if...else` too